# Set the CALayer blending mode using CIFilters

Tags: cocoa, calayer

I'm trying to using the property backgroundFilters of a CALayer to manage a sort of Blendmode.

This is my current structure:

```
LAYER A 
   |
   |_______LAYER B
```

- The `Layer A` content is an image.
- The `Layer B` is a sublayer of the `Layer A` and it has red backgroundColor

What I'm trying to do is blending the content of the `Layer A` using the backgroundColor of the `Layer B`.

I added to `B` a filter this way:

```
    CIFilter *blending = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorBlendMode"];
    blending.name = @"blendingFilter";

    [blending setDefaults];
    layerB.filters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:blending];
```

But it doesn't work.

Which is the right way to create a colorBlending effect between 2 layers?

(I'm working on OSX not iOS)